# Limit ajax autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, autocomplete

How do you limit the number of search result given that the data is not local. I know local data can be easily limited as shown below.

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myarray, request.term);

    response(results.slice(0, 10));`
```

This is not working quite well when I get my data externally. Below is my code.

```
 $(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "/accounts/ajax/search/",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui ){
        window.open(ui.item.url,'_self')},
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').append("<li><a class = \" text-primary\" href='javascript:document.getElementById(\"search_form\").submit();'> See All Result </a></li>");
         },
  });
});
```

Comment: The most efficient way would be to limit the results server side.

Comment: Your `source` seems to be missing some critical code.... all you've done is overwrite some variable? Where's the request? You should be able to slice the result exactly like you've done in your first example (assuming you can't do it server-side).

Comment: Small mistake, Just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make the ajax request yourself and pass the limited results to response callback.

By default, when source is a string, a GET request is made to the provided string with a parameter of name term and value the input value. So you have to reproduce this:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
          $.get('/accounts/ajax/search/', { term: request.term}, function(results) {
               response(results.slice(0, 10));
          });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the [value for source with a function](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) and then do the ajax request and result processing manually:

```
$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.get("/accounts/ajax/search?term=" + request.term, function(data) {
        //limit results here
        response(data.slice(0, 10));
      });
    },
    ...
  });
});
```